# Blinn-Phong illumination - what is the best calculation of the complete color

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, phong

Almost all of the articles and books that I've read state that the composition of the final color is:
finalColor = ambientColor + lambertianTerm * diffuseColor ( = material color ) + specularIntensity * specularColor ( = light color )

```
lambertianTerm = dot( surfaceNormal, normalize( lightPos - surfacePos ) );

halfVector = normalize( normalize( lightPos - surfacePos ) + normalize( eyePos - surfacePos );
specularFactor = max( dot( halfVector, surfaceNormal ), 0.0f );

specularIntensity = pow( specularFactor, surfaceShininessLevel );
```

Here are some of the places that use the aforementioned approach for calculating the final color: OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition -> Rendering Techniques -> Lighting Models -> Blinn-Phong Lighting, [Wikipedia -> Blinn–Phong shading model (see the fragment shader)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model), and others.

There is a problem in the calculation of the final color: the light's color (also consider the multiple light sources case) does not participate in the formulation of the diffuse color. Consider the case where the shininess factor is a large number - 128.0 let's say, so that the specular spot is small and most of the object's area is colored using the diffuse term. Also let the object's color be green and the light's one - red. The output of the equation above if there is no ambient color is a partially lit purely green object with a small yellow spot on it = green + red = the light from the red light source reflected from the green object:
[image: purely green diffuse color + yellow specular highlight]
This is not correct. Of course, green + red is yellow, but for sure you will see neither purely green ball nor a yellow specular spot. Hold a green shiny ball in your hand - for instance the big 6 from a billiard game, and then light it up with a red light - I could assure you you won't see only green diffuse and yellow specular. Instead you would see a blended green + red for the diffuse and more red specular spot. The best way I've found so far to calculate the final color - average blending:

```
finalColor = ambient
             + lambertianTerm * ( surfaceColor + lightColor ) / 2.0 
             + specularIntensity * lightColor;
```

[image: diffuse = yellow with a red accent, specular spot = almost purely red]
Tried overlay blending:

```
const vec4 srgbLuminanceFactor = vec4( 0.2125f, 0.7154f, 0.0721f, 1.0f );
vec4 overlay( vec4 baseColor, vec4 blendColor )
{
    float luminance = dot( baseColor, srgbLuminanceFactor );
    vec4 lowerLumOverlay = 2.0f * blendColor * baseColor;
    if ( luminance < 0.45f )
    {
        return lowerLumOverlay;
    }

    const vec4 whiteColor = vec4( 1.0 );
    vec4 higherLumOverlay = whiteColor - 2.0f * ( whiteColor - blendColor ) * ( whiteColor - baseColor );
    return luminance > 0.55f
           ? higherLumOverlay
           : mix( lowerLumOverlay, higherLumOverlay, ( luminance - 0.45f ) * 10.0f );
}
```

... but doesn't look good.
Probably the light and object's color should be mixed in another linear ratio:

```
mix( surfaceColor, lightColor, ratio );
```

... or in a non-linear way which I cannot think of.

So the final question: what is the best calculation of the complete color?
Also, tell me if I am missing something but to my opinion the pure green picture + pure yellow specular highlight is totally not a real world scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Surface color meaning is "what light's colors can be **diffused** from this surface".

Specular color meaning is "what light's colors can be **reflected** from this surface".

Light color meaning is "what light's colors reaching surface".

So you must multiply them:

```
   finalColor = ambient
             + lambertianTerm * surfaceColor * lightColor
             + specularIntensity * specularColor * lightColor;
```